Ошибка TypeError. Моя функция ничего не возвращает, хотя операторы return есть. FLASK, SQLALCHEMY, PYTHON
Получаю такую ошибку при попытке изменить данные в базе данных sqlalchemy на flask:

TypeError The view function for 'editcomplete' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Хочу сделать возможность изменять логин пользователя в базе данных.
@app.route('/users/<int:id>/edit/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def editlogin(id):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(id)
    return render_template('editlogin.html', user=user)
    
@app.route('/users/<int:id>/edit/login/complete')
def editcomplete(id):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(id)

    newlogin = request.form.get('newlogin')
    oldlogin = User.query.order_by(User.login).all()
    login_list = []
    for el in oldlogin:
        login_list.append(el.login)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if not (newlogin):
            flash('Пожалуйста заполните поля')
        elif newlogin in login_list:
            flash('Такой логин уже существует!')
        else:
            flash('Логин изменен!')
            db.session.query(User.login).update({'login': f'{newlogin}'})
            db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('users'))

{% if user %}
    <div class="goods">
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
            {% if messages %}
                <div class=flashes>
                    {% for message in messages %}
                    <p>{{ message }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        <form id="editor" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <input class="auth-form" type="text" name="newlogin" placeholder="Новый логин" required>
        </form>
        <p><a href="/users/{{ user.id }}/edit/login/complete" class="completebtn">Сохранить</a></p>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="goods goodscenter">
        <p>Произошла ошибка :(</p>
    </div>
{% endif %}


Во-первых, вы не отправляете форму. Во-вторых, если условие if request.method == "POST": не выполняется, то ваша функция возвращает что?

Что значит отправить форму?

Ну если вы даже такие базовые вещи не знаете, то вам нужно начинать с чтения учебников https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Спасибо, я только учусь)
